# drainage basin for whole lake QGIS 2.18.7

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, watershed, basin

I am currently facing a problem. Over the past week, I have been initiated to hydrology within the GIS environment and have finally successfully generated water basins (using the GRASS r.water.outlet) by selecting a pixel in my Flow direction raster generated from a DEM with r.stream.extract

My problem is as follows: I would like to be able to select any pixel (with or without a geoalgorithm) and obtain the whole water basin complex leading to this lake. I know the lake retains water and it's odd because the information generated through my DEM says otherwise. Where a wall should hold the water in, the DEM and all the treatments claim that water goes out through there.

Perhaps the precision of my DEM is lacking, but I can see the wall with a generated Hillshade so I doubt it...

Is there a way to manually modify the DEM for my treatments to detect there is a wall there and the lake is all at the same level? Or is there an existing geoalgorithm that can detect such a lake in the creation of watersheds and water basins? the GRASS commands seem limited in this topic to simply giving me the basins partially through lines.

Mainly though, I would like to be able to do the water basin request from a polygon or a general area in the raster.

Answer (score 2):

The GRASS watershed algorithm, by design, continues to route water flow across lakes (or any other flat areas or depressions). It stops when reaching either the edge of the region, or a null cell.

So if you just set your lake to null values the basin will end there. If you have a polygon vector of the lake, then convert to raster with

`v.to.rast lake output=lake type=area use=val value=1`

Then use a mapcalc expression to set the dem to null over the lake, but keep the dem values everywhere else:

`r.mapcalc "dem_lake_null =  if(lake==1, null(), dem)"`

Now rerun your watershed process with this new dem.

Comment: The first v.to.rast works fine, however the mapcalc expression returns absolutely nothing. if i re-write with input/output values it would be something like this right? : 
r.mapcalc "output = if(inputLakeRaster==1, null(), inputDEM)" right?

Also, if I modify my DEM like this, would the future water basin request I was talking about return a result for the whole lake?

Comment: I forgot to mention: set the region to the dem, `g.region rast=dem`.

Comment: I've been exploring this problem and the solutions possible for it and found another post in which you answered that helped me alot which is this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223992/get-drainage-basin-of-a-polygon-with-qgis-grass-or-other-foss

Comment: However I'm trying to get the knack of GRASS GIS as a whole, I initially thought it was simple functions available in QGIS, I didn't think it was a whole GIS system in as of it'self. I will certainly keep this post up to date and try these suggestions you gave me in GRASS GIS.

Comment: GRASS GIS is most certainly a fullblown GIS application in its own right, with a rich set of vector and raster analysis modules and over 30 years of development. Well worth the time to get familiar with it.

Comment: Indeed, I am super excited, as a new recruit just graduating college in geomatics, to get to learn all these new (to me) applications and possibilities. Plus I am just starting to touch hydrology analysis and it is, to say the least, fascinating.

Comment: Still on this problem, if I do this, won't I have "empty" watersheds around the lake which are the areas draining directly into the lake? If what I've gathered so far about watersheds is right, won't the watershed only be calculated by the water flow route? much information will not be taken into account. My big question is how to make the lake apart of that water flow and that calculation. (Is there an application that calculates watershed on a polygon, basically?)

Comment: Also I've been reading a lot on this topic and have gathered that there is the possibility of 'burning' streams and lakes to a specific elevation in the DEM. This process seems to be mainly done in ArcGIS with Arc Hydro and the Spacial analyst extension. Do you know if it is an acceptable practice to modify the DEM like this? And do you know of a way to do this in QGIS/GRASS GIS? I am open to working with these tools as well as ArcGIS.

Comment: The GRASS module for burning a stream into a DEM raster is called `r.carve`. [https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.carve.html] (man page)

Comment: If you NULL out the lake, then the watersheds will end at the lake edge. The only empty parts will be areas that are smaller than the flow accumulation threshold that you set.