# Does r.stream.basin still exist? GRASS-QGIS2.18.7

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, watershed, basin

So I'm following steps in another topic that seems to date to January of this year and is exactly what I want to do, here's the link: [Get drainage basin of a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223992/get-drainage-basin-of-a-polygon-with-qgis-grass-or-other-foss)  and at one of the last steps in Mr. Micha's explanation (who has helped me a **lot** this past week) in which he suggests to run r.stream.basins using the **flow direction** map as input and intersection points as parameter, I can't find any algorithm asking for such a parameter. I have everything that is needed (**Flow direction** as well as **Intersection points**) and have been browsing for a few hours to no avail. I'm wondering if it's my QGIS version or simply GRASS GIS 7 not having such a function.

Has it changed name and description?

Does it still exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module r.stream.basins is an addon:

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/r.stream.basins.html

In order to use it from QGIS, you need to have the module being installed in the underlying GRASS GIS installation.

Comment: Thanks for this enlightening answer, I had no idea GRASS was actually a GIS in it'self. I will keep you up to date on the result.

Comment: Here you find more addons: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/