# r.stream.basin in qgis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, grass-7.0

I am trying to generate subbasin with provided multiple outlets points by using r.stream.basin. I have install r.stream.basin addon in grass but it does not appear in qgis. Is there any ways to use this addon in qgis??

answer posted here [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238950/does-r-stream-basin-still-exist-grass-qgis2-18-7) does not help.

Comment: That depends on how QGIS manages GRASS GIS addons - to show up in the menu of "Processing" an instruction text file containing parameters etc needs to be added

Comment: Thanks @markusN, yes I got the error message like as you said 'metafile is not found'. Actually which one is metafile for r.stream.basin in this link that I need to add: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass7/raster/r.stream.basins

Comment: No, it is a QGIS metadata file describing how the GRASS GIS module works, see here for examples: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description